# Undefined symbol Import Error Boost Python

Tags: python, c++, makefile, cmake, boost-python

I have 2 C++ classes that I am trying to export to python via boost.  Below is the boost python module:

```
#include "/path/to/header.h"
namespace bp = boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module){
    bp::class_< metadata >( "metadata" )    
        .def_readwrite( "id", &metadata::id )    
        .def_readwrite( "status", &metadata::status );

    bp::class_< device >( "device" )    
        .def( 
            "deviceConnect"
            , (bool (*)( ::metadata,bool const ))( &::device::deviceConnect )
            , ( bp::arg("meta"), bp::arg("verbose") ) )    
        .def( 
            "deviceStatus"
            , (bool (*)( ::metadata,::std::string const,bool const ))( &::device::deviceStatus )
            , ( bp::arg("meta"), bp::arg("id"), bp::arg("verbose") ) )        
        .staticmethod( "deviceConnect" )    
        .staticmethod( "deviceStatus" );
}
```

The 2 classes are device and metadata and they are both defined in the included header. I build the code using the below cmakelists.txt and it outputs an SO file that I attempt to import into a python script.

```
project(device_pylib)

  # Find default python libraries and interpreter
  find_package (Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development )
  find_package(Boost 1.65.1 COMPONENTS python3 )

  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  # Build and link the pylib_auto module
  
  add_library(device SHARED /path/to/boost/module.cpp)

  target_link_libraries(device ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${Python3_LIBRARIES})

  add_dependencies(device Boost::python3)

  # Tweaks the name of the library to match what Python expects

  set_target_properties(device PROPERTIES SUFFIX .so)
  set_target_properties(device PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Everything builds fine and the SO file is built correctly. However, when I go to import it into my python script as such:

```
from module import device
```

Once I run the python script, it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: /path/to/shared/object/module.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6device12deviceStatusE8metadataNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb
```

I am pretty sure this has to do with passing in the object from the metadata class into the member functions of the device class. Whenever I strip those out of the function prototypes, it runs fine. Is there something I am doing wrong in my above configuration?

Comment: Yeah the error still persists. sorry for the confusion, I also had a typo in the mangled name in the import error. I corrected it now.

Comment: I am using gcc 7.5.0

Comment: No worries! Yeah i was modifying the names for the class and I accidentally copied an earlier error. Now it should all match up.

Comment: Yeah that is the correct signature from my device class header: `static bool deviceStatus( metadata meta, const std::string id, const bool verbose);`. Would it have anything to do with including the metadata object in the device class methods?

Comment: What would I need to change the function signatures to in the headers? Am I not referencing the metadata class correctly in the function signature?

Comment: (Recap & Clean comments:) The error seems to say, that the 
dynamic-linker/loader, is searching for the symbol (function) 
`device::deviceStatus(metadata, std::string, bool)`, and cannot find it. 
(Running `c++filt -n _ZN6device12deviceStatusE8metadataNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb` 
will show this.) (More than that, I cannot say.)

Comment: Where's the implementation of the two classes you've created wrappers for? Presumably not in `module.cpp`, but in some other file which you didn't compile and link the result?